# Sending first half to Target

Tags: talend

I want to try out the famous Scenario of sending the first half of a file/table to a Target.How to achieve this via Talend?

```
Id,Name
1,Abhijit
2,Subir
3,Bimal
4,Kabir
```

I am using tmap to generate sequence number but can't proceed after that

Comment: Kindly provide the screenshot of your job design and provide the details of source data.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the component : tSampleRow

You put the code inside : "1..X" with X your number of line divide by 2.

Comment: AmanKino yeah i checked a lot and able to send it.thanks a lot again :)